# getAllItems() returns an empty List in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I need to get all the MavenModuleSet objects in Jenkins and my code is:

```
List<MavenModuleSet> list = Jenkins.getInstance().getAllItems(MavenModuleSet.class);
```

When I run it (in a Jenkins plugin) on my local machine the list contains all the items, on the server the list is empty.

Any idea why?

Comment: Are permissions set up? I believe Administrator needs to have the READ  (Item.READ) permission set up.

Comment: Hi Steve
you are right. I found out that the plugin is run by the user Anonymous and I had to update the authorization matrix for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few tests I can confirm the problem was related to the permissions for the user "anonymous".
The plugin is ran by the anonymous user and I modified the Jenkins "Matrix-based security" to give the user CRUD authorization for Jobs.

Comment: Hi @Emanuele , I am also having the same problem but in my case I cannot provide read access to "anonymous" user. Could you please let me know how to proceed here ?

Comment: Hi @ObuliSundar I'm afraid I'm not using it anymore and don't know how to support you :(